# PHP7 and pdo_mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo, windows-10, php-7

I've just upgraded PHP5.6 to PHP7 on my XAMPP on Windows 10 [following this guide](http://tektriks.com/how-to-upgrade-php-5-6-to-php-7-in-xampp-on-windows/). It works just fine, except for PDO.

In my phpinfo() I get `PDO support enabled, PDO drivers no value`.
I copied the php.ini-development and renamed it to php.ini, and I have uncommented the extension folder declaration, and the extention driver php_pdo_mysql.dll.

```
extension_dir = "ext"
...
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

I have verified that php_pdo_mysql.dll is located in C:\xampp\php\ext and when I run `php -m` in a console, both PDO and pdo_mysql are listed as active modules.

```
C:\xampp\php>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
filter
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

When I run a script that utilizes PDO, I get thrown
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in (path to script)`

The script I am running is completely valid and worked fine before the upgrade (basically just a `new PDO(params)`).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, not sure why, Windows needs an absolute path to the extension dir. So instead of

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

in php.ini, I put

```
extension_dir = "C:/xampp/php/ext"
```

and then restarted apache. Everything works again.

Maybe someone can elaborate on this issue?